# Varargs to ArrayList problem in Java

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

I don't understand why the following does not work:

```
public void doSomething(int... args){
  List<Integer> broken = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(args))
}
```

Its my understanding that the compiler converts the "int... args" to an array, so the above code should work.

Instead of working I get:

> cannot find symbol
>   symbol:   constructor ArrayList(java.util.List`<int[]`>)
>   location: class java.util.ArrayList`<java.lang.Integer`>

Thats bizarre. I'm not adding an array to array list, I'm adding each element from the list to the arraylist. Whats going on?

Comment: b/c you are making List<int[]> effectively, change the `int... args` to `Integer... args` and you might get lucky

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Java cannot autobox an array, only individual values. I would suggest changing your method signature to

```
public void doSomething(Integer... args)
```

Then the autoboxing will take place when calling `doSomething`, rather than trying (and failing) when calling `Arrays.asList`.

What is happening is Java is now autoboxing each individual value as it is passed to your function. What you were trying to do before was, by passing an `int[]` to `Arrays.asList()`, you were asking that function to do the autoboxing.

But autoboxing is implemented by the compiler -- it sees that you needed an object but were passing a primitive, so it automatically inserted the necessary code to turn it into an appropriate object. The `Arrays.asList()` function has already been compiled and expects objects, and the compiler cannot turn an `int[]` into an `Integer[]`.

By moving the autoboxing to the callers of your function, you've solved that problem.

Comment: Oh! Works. Could you explain why that is, though? I guess I would assume that behind the scenes when you pass a collection to an arraylist, each element is added to the array list (although now that I think about it, I suppose that ArrayList could be just a view of some collection). Please enlighten me, if you can! Thanks.

Comment: @Ben B, it does much the same thing as addAll() for collections or putAll() for Map.

Comment: I know what addAll() does, but not how it does it.

Comment: It's basically `Object[] a = c.toArray();` and `System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);` where c is the collection and elementData is the backing array of the ArrayList.

Comment: `doSomething(1,2,3)` results in `Integer[] a = {1,2,3}`, then `Arrays.asList(a)` results in a `List<Integer>`. Furthermore `addAll(...)` creates a `Object[]` array, which works since `Integer` extends `Object`.

Comment: @jonathan "But autoboxing is implemented by the compiler -- it sees that you needed an object but were passing a primitive"(quote from your answer) Is not int[] an object? because i know arrays are objects.

Comment: Yes, `int[]` is an object, but it contains `int`s not `Integer`s. It is not a one-step conversion from `int[]` to `Integer[]` as every element must be visited and converted individually.

Answer (score 32):

You can do

```
public void doSomething(int... args){
    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(args.length);
    for(int i: args) ints.add(i);
}
```

or

```
public void doSomething(Integer... args){
    List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(args);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can solve this using Guava:

```
List<Integer> broken = new ArrayList<>(Ints.asList(args))
```

Or with streams:

```
List<Integer> broken = Arrays
    .stream(array)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: `boxed()` is a nice solution

Answer (score 8):

In this case, autoboxing (automatic conversion from `int` to `Integer`) doesn't work. You have to add each `int` manually to the list.

If you need code like that often, consider using [commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) which has `org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils.toObject(int[])`